# ExpressJs - Getting Server Sub-routes to work with Angular factory svcs

Tags: angularjs, express, routes

For easy maintenance, I would like to compartmentalize my server routes:

**server.js (start app):**

```
require('./routes/allRoutes')(app);
```

---

**allRoutes.js:**

```
module.exports = function(app){
  //don't I need to pass (app) below? This will not work as is
  var Group1 = require('../routes/Group1/groupRoutes')(app), 
      Group2 = require('../routes/Group2/groupRoutes')(app);

  app.use('/group1', Group1);
  app.use('/group2', Group2);
}
```

---

**groupRoutes.js: (in Group1 Folder)**

```
module.exports = function(app){
  //don't I need to pass (app) below? This will not work as is
  var SubGroup1 = require('../routes/Group1/subGroup1Route')(app);
      .....
  app.use('/subgroup1', SubGroup1);
}
```

---

**subGroup1Routes.js: (in Group1 Folder)**

```
var FooCrtl = require('../../controllers/Group1/subGroup1/FooCtrl');

module.exports = function(app){
   app.get('/api/foo', FooCtrl.get);
   app.post('/api/foo', FooCtrl.post);
}
```

---

**AngularJs FooSvcs:**

```
....
   return {
        getFoo: function(){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',

                url: '/group1/subgroup1/api/foo', <--- NOT WORKING

            });
        },
```

Two-Fold issues:

1. On the server side do I not need to pass the "app" as a parameter down the routes tree? I tried but recv'd an error.
2. In the scenario above, what is the correct url for my angular factory as I what have does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was a tough one but I finally solved it.

1. My desire to compartmentalize my route structure on the server side to mirror my module structure on the client [angular] side is the right approach.
2. Where I erred was in thinking I needed to create a *tree structure* [**<-- WRONG**] for my server routes and that is **NOT** the case.

### **The Example:**

***Client [angular] side:***

> ```
> public
>  ---- app
>     ---- module A folder
>     ---- module B folder
>     ---- module C folder
> ```

***Server [express] side structure:***

> ```
> server
>  ---- routes
>     ---- route A folder
>         --- foo apis
>         --- bar apis
>     ---- route B folder
>     ---- route C folder
> ```

---

**foo api on server side structure:**

> ```
> var express = require('express'),
> FooCtl = require('../../controllers/foo/FooCtl');
>
> module.exports = function(app){
>    app.get('/api/foo', FooCtl.get);
> ....
> }
> ```

I do not need to create a "parent route" to collect on my routes in that folder.

Instead, using "***npm install --save wrench***" in my root, server.js:

> ```
> var express = require('express'),
>     path = require('path'),
>     wrench = require('wrench');
>
> wrench.readdirRecursive("routes", function (error, files) {
>        if(files != null){
>        files.forEach(function (file) {
>                if (file.indexOf('.js') > -1 && file != undefined) {
>                    fullPath = ('./routes/' + file);
>                    console.log(fullPath);
>                    require(fullPath)(app);
>                }
>        })} });
> ```

***And everything works!***